# jQuery: Toggle - List

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, toggle, jquery-animate

*This is a continuation from here:* [jQuery: List expands on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590666/jquery-list-expands-on-page-load)

Hi,

Since my previous post, I've worked on another list and come up with this: http://jsbin.com/emaza4/4

As you may see, the first `<li>` element with a `<ul>` child (item '#') opens automatically on page load, and the other "parents" stay closed until any one of them is clicked. I achieved this by putting item '#' under class 'abc' and the rest of the items under class 'xyz'.

Next, I would like to be able to click on another parent, say, item "A-F" and it automatically closes any other opened parent, including item '#' that's from a different class ('abc' instead of 'xyz').

Searching "toggle" on this website led me to this: [jQuery toggle dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593953/jquery-toggle-dynamically)

So I tried adding to my code like so: http://jsbin.com/emaza4/3/ but it doesn't seem to be working.

Could anybody point me in the right direction as to how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the hide-only version of [`.toggle('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) ([`.hide('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)), on the siblings of the clicked `<li>` in each of your handlers, like this:

```
$(this).siblings().children().hide('slow');
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsbin.com/emaza4/5).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you make the problem a bit overcomplicated. All you need is onclick hide all the sub-menus and open the relevant one. eg.

```
$('li').click(function (){
  $('ul').hide();
  $(this).find('ul').show();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i decided to go with Nick Craver's solution :)